# Discord.py: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'change_presence'

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, nonetype

FIXED, fix = await ctx.bot.change_presence.

This is my code for a command that worked with @bot.command() but somehow it doesn't work when I use @commands.command()

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = !)

@commands.command()
async def playgame(ctx, game: str=None):
    game_count = False
    game_list = []

    if game:
        game_list.append(game)
        game_activity = discord.Activity(name=game, type=discord.ActivityType.playing)
        activity = discord.Activity(name=".commands", type=discord.ActivityType.listening)
        if game_count:
            await ctx.send("I'm already playing " + str(game_list[0]))
        else:
            game_count = True
            await ctx.send("ok!")
            await bot.change_presence(activity=game_activity) #This calls the error
            await asyncio.sleep(60)
            await ctx.send("Gotta go, imma stop playing " + str(game_list[0]) + ", bye")
            await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.dnd, activity=activity)
            game_count = False
            game_lib = []
    else:
        msg = "I can't play nothing, use .playgame <game>"
        await ctx.send(msg)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_command(playgame)
```

Comment: You need to either specify the `bot` variable inside the function or import global `bot` variable using `global bot` inside your function.

Comment: Tried the first one already, just tried globaling bot but neither work. Gives the same error.

Comment: You shouldn’t define the bot again inside the extension

Comment: Tried doing that and got the error that 'bot' is not defined. I then tried to put it in a try except Exception: pass but somehow the exception didn't get caught.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is just that little thing that you didn't put the command prefix in quotation marks so it is not formatted as string and messes up the whole script.

Solution would be:

`bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")`

*Just noticed you already fixed it